# SimpleXML and PHP

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

I have a quick question on this, I've seen other posts and they still didn't really help with this particular xml navigation I am trying to do between the XML objects.

The XML output is as follows (data is stripped, but the structure is there, still):

```
<hashtable>
 <entry>
  <string>+++++++1+++++++</string>
   <hashtable>
    <entry>
      <string></string>
      <string>DATA I WANT TO RETRIEVE IS HERE</string>
    </entry>
    <entry>
      <string></string>
      <boolean></boolean>
    </entry>
    <entry>
      <string></string>
      <string></string>
    </entry>
   </hashtable>
  </entry>
</hashtable>
```

I can not for the life of me get this to work.

I have tried something similar to `$xml->entry['0']->string` and I received the string that I labeled `+++++++1+++++++` in the above XML response. I don't know how to get to what I am wanting, which is the string I labeled `DATA I WANT TO RETRIEVE IS HERE`.

My `simplexml_load_file(#)` is called by `$xml`;

Can anyone possibly provide an easy way to understand how i can retrieve the data in the string I labeled as `DATA I WANT TO RETRIEVE IS HERE`? How should I go about retrieving this particular `<string></string>`?

Comment: You did not say what you want to do . just understand 'this' ? what is 'this'.

Comment: Updated the last part to explain what I want to do.

Comment: You did not say how you are trying to get the node.

Comment: Updated to explain what I have tried, just not sure what path to take to get to this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, the trick is to convert the Object back to string by adding a '':

```
        $a = "<hashtable>
     <entry>
      <string></string>
       <hashtable>
        <entry>
          <string></string>
          <string>DATA I WANT TO RETRIEVE IS HERE</string>
        </entry>
        <entry>
          <string></string>
          <boolean></boolean>
        </entry>
        <entry>
          <string></string>
          <string></string>
        </entry>
       </hashtable>
      </entry>
    </hashtable>";

    $xml = simplexml_load_string($a);
    echo  $xml->entry->hashtable->entry[0]->string[1].''; //print DATA I WANT TO RETRIEVE IS HERE
```

Comment: That did it! So, here's my question, does the initial hashtable not matter?

Comment: Yes, root tag name does not matter

Answer (score 0):

You should look up xPath at https://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.xpath.php
Something along the line of this:

```
...    
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($string);
    
$result = $xml->xpath('/hashtable/entry/hashtable/entry/string');
    
while(list( , $node) = each($result)) {
    echo '/hashtable/entry/hashtable/entry/string: ',$node,"\n";
}
...
```

Please note - the xPath used will give all nodes that match (more than you intended...)

Comment: Thanks for that! But in the event that this one has 2 string's listed in the entry, how would I retrieve the second one?

Comment: You could use something like /hashtable/entry/hashtable/entry/string[2] to get the second one, but that will result in 2 matches in the provided sample...